# How to function on string in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

when I update user data, show me error `Call to a member function getKeyName() on string`. I don't know why this error is. I will gratefull if someone help me resolve this.

model

```
class Customer extends Model
 {
use HasFactory;

protected $fillable = [
    'first_name',
    'last_name',
    'email',
    'phone_number'
];

public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'id';
}

}
```

controller

```
public function update(CustomerRequest $request)
{
   Customer::updated($request->validated());

    return redirect()->route('customers.index')->with('updateMessage', 'Customer data successfully updated');
}
```

Comment: do you have the code on github? because there is a problem on somewhere else...

Comment: @MohamadFazelHesari I don't want to show everyone me github profile

Comment: Can you share the `CustomerRequest` class and the route?

Comment: @MohamadFazelHesari please do not encourage ppl to post links to code off-site.  Questions on SO should include the minimum required code to reproduce the problem **here**, on SO.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: `Customer::updated($request->validated());` should probably be `Customer::update($request->validated());` . I think `updated` refers to the model updated event perhaps?

Comment: @perh23 the picture you have uploaded doesn't show anything about the problem you have, just upload a picture of where you get the error!

Answer (score 0):

you should use the `update` method instead `updated`, the `updated` method is one of the [model events](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#events) in laravel, and when you update an instance of the model, the `updated` method run after that.